# Cannot load data from text file to MySQL table

Tags: mysql, heidisql

I have a text file with millions of rows.

Example: *sorage.txt*

```
foo
bar
baz
```

File was loaded as follows:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/sorage.txt'
INTO TABLE `storage` (@word)
SET col1 = @word, col2 = CONCAT('prefix_', @word)
```

Afterwards I doesn't see any rows in the `storage` table. But table statistics shows that rows exist.

I'm using MySQL 5.7 and HeidiSQL as GUI.

**Pic 1**

[image: table statistics]

**Pic 2**

[image: select rows from table]

Why there are no rows?

**Update 1**

Using terminal - *0* rows.

[image: query table from the console]

Comment: This is strange. If I use your query in command-line mysql, it works fine. It reports the correct number of rows inserted and 'SELECT...' shows them correctly. If I do it in PHPMyAdmin, I get 'MySQL returned an empty result set' but it does actually insert them. I'd suspect heidisql.

Comment: @Nick My first test query was using a text file with a couple of rows and it worked (rows were present in the Heidi).

Comment: Just tried it again with 1.2 million random words and both methods work as with the small test file. Using MySQL 5.7.22.

Comment: @Mate There was one query only. `COMMIT;` doesn't help.

Comment: @Nick  Hm... I did it two times and without any success.

Comment: If you try select * from stg LIMIT 10; ?

Comment: Most likely, you are inserting into the wrong server, the wrong database or the wrong table (e.g. `storage`/`_storage` asin your query/pictures). Try `SELECT @@hostname, database();` and compare the values. Another option is that you are not committing; you already check, but recheck and do a commit (just in case) and do the `select count(*)` directly after the `load data`, so it is certainly in the same transaction (and the same server/database), in case there is one. Also: does the import take significant time? (Just to make sure you are not importing an empty file).

Comment: @Mate, I got empty result.

Comment: @Solarflare, It is my localhost, db and table are correct. Import takes about 2 hours. I will try to debug the *commit* version one more time.